# MATLAB fitting matrices

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, function-fitting

I got the case `P(t) = a * A(t) - b* B(t)`, each 17281x1 doubles.

Now I want to use curve fitting to get the variables `a` and `b`.

[image: Fitting 1]

*Fitting case, here a and b as 1 and 1*

I know `fit` and `fittype`, but they seem not to work in this case.

> Any ideas, how to get this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the least squares method? If I understand correctly, your problem could be expressed as 
`P(t) = [A(t), B(t)] * [a; -b]`.

Let `[a; -b] = x`, `[A(t), B(t)] = Y` and `P(t) = P`

Now the least squares solution would be:

```
x = ((Y'*Y)^-1)*Y'*P;
```

In Matlab you could also use the 'backslash operator' for this case:

```
x = Y\P;
```

for this, you'll find the documentation here: [mldivide](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html)

As a reference:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)

[Mathworks](https://de.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html)

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Here's my test code:

```
A = [1;2;3]
B = [4;5;6]
P = [7;8;9]

Y = [A, -B]

disp('------- regular least squares formula -------')
x = ((Y'*Y)^-1)*Y'*P

a = x(1)
b = x(2)

disp('------- mldivide -------')
x = Y\P

a = x(1)
b = x(2)
```

Comment: Sorry, I adjusted my answer and tried a little example on my computer, with this approach I think you should get your solution

Comment: Thx,
but how to do `[a; -b] = x` as there are Multiple left-hand sides

can you just copy yur code please

Comment: I just used `[a; -b] = x` so that I could replace `[a; -b]` with `x` in the formula, as a simplification, and because the solution of the least squares method would be a column vector, that I just named `x`. I added my test code to my answer.

Comment: That's great, glad i could help!